# Is value category of function returning by value is always xvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move, xvalue

As per my understanding below code should call move constructor of `Test` class since this function is returning by value which means expression `GetTestObj()` should be rvalue and xvalues are implicitly moved but why this code is calling copy constructor ?

```
class Test
{
  public:
         Test()
         {
         }
         Test(const Test& arg)
         {
            std::cout<<"Copy Constructor Called..."<<std::endl;
         }
         Test(Test&& arg)
         {
            std::cout<<"Move Constructor Called..."<<std::endl;
         }
};

Test  GetMyTestObj()
{
      Test *ptr = new Test();
      return *ptr;
}
Test dummy = GetMyTestObj(); //Copy Constructor Called...
```

Comment: It very much depends on the `Test` class definition. Have you tried making the copy-constructor deleted? You have a move-constructor? And you do know you have a memory leak in that code you show? Why not simply create a simple `Test` object instance in the function (e.g. `Test test;`) and return it?

Answer (score 2):

In your code there is actually one copy from `*ptr` into the return value and one move from `GetMyTestObj()` to `dummy`. However, the compiler [elides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) the move, so you won't see it traced. If you pass `-fno-elide-constructors` to GCC or Clang then you should see the copy and the move ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d626b632c296e0ad)).

If you want the construction of the return value to a move, you need to use `std::move`:

```
Test GetMyTestObj()
{
      Test *ptr = new Test();
      return std::move(*ptr);
}
```

However, there's really no need for dynamic allocation in this instance; it's inefficient and leaks memory with your implementation. You should just use an automatic variable:

```
Test GetMyTestObj()
{
    Test test;
    //I assume you're doing something else here
    return test;
}
```

With the above code, the compiler can actually elide both constructions.

If you're doing nothing else in that function, you should just construct `dummy` directly:

```
Test dummy{};
```

Answer (score 0):

> which means expression `GetTestObj()` should be rvalue and xvalues are implicitly moved

Firstly, answer your question directly, `GetTestObj()` is a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue).

> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression of non-reference return type, such as `str.substr(1, 2)`, `str1 + str2`, or `it++`;

The point is that copy/move operation is needed for `return *ptr;`; `ptr` is a named variable, which is a [lvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue). `*ptr` is lvalue too, it can't be moved.

You could use `std::move` explicitly to make it a xvalue to be movable:

```
return std::move(*ptr);
```

Comment: but what is value category of expression GetMyTestObj()

Comment: @Kapil It's a prvalue; but doesn't matter here. Copy occurs in return statement.

Comment: `std::move` is irrelevant here because it is implicitly applied to return value unless copy elision occurs. This is described in standard. So, basically, adding `std::move` to return statement can only prevent optimization

Comment: @AndreiR. This case doesn't meet the rules for treating the return as an rvalue, so the `std::move` is necessary. Imagine if `ptr` was some global state; you'd be pretty surprised if you moved the pointee just by returning it by value.

Comment: @AndreiR. It's not irrelevant, it's used to explain why copy ctor is needed here, i.e. why `*ptr` can't be moved.

Comment: converting lvalue reference to temporary cannot be done without copying, which occurs irrelevantly to `std::move`

Answer (score 0):

value is copied not here (no constructor is called due to copy elision):

```
Test dummy = GetMyTestObj();
```

but here:

```
return *ptr;
```

because function has to make rvalue object from lvalue reference. Basically, `GetMyTestObj()` function in this case is equivalent to:

```
Test *ptr = new Test();
Test returnValue(*ptr);
return returnValue;
```